# Creating linked Lists in Java

Tags: java, linked-list

I am pretty new to Java and I wanted to test some data structures out so I create a really BASIC linked list but adding a bunch of nodes together.

Here is my node class:

```
public class LinkedListNode {
    public LinkedListNode next;
    int data;


    // constructor
    LinkedListNode(int newData) {
        this.data = newData;
    }

    public void addNode(LinkedListNode root, LinkedListNode node) {
        if (root.next == null) {
            root.next = node;
        }
        else {
            addNode(root.next, node);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is how I created the nodes:

```
LinkedListNode root = new LinkedListNode(4);    // root
LinkedListNode a = new LinkedListNode(16);
LinkedListNode b = new LinkedListNode(8);
LinkedListNode c = new LinkedListNode(23);
LinkedListNode d = new LinkedListNode(99);
LinkedListNode e = new LinkedListNode(1);
LinkedListNode f = new LinkedListNode(2);
LinkedListNode g = new LinkedListNode(5);
LinkedListNode h = new LinkedListNode(12);
```

I want to add the nodes together using my `addNode` method but I am getting this error in eclipse:

```
root.addNode(root,b);

Multiple markers at this line
- Syntax error on token ")", delete this 
 token
- Syntax error on token "(", delete this 
 token
```

I was wondering if anyone could help me out fixing this problem. If someone else has another method of creating linked lists I would be happy to read it!

I also tried moving the `addNode` method outside of my `LinkedListNode` class and using

`addNode(root,b)`

But this gives me the error:

```
Multiple markers at this line
    - Syntax error on token ",", delete this 
     token
    - root cannot be resolved to a type
    - Return type for the method is missing
```

Comment: Your `addNode` method receives 2 parameters, you are just passing 1.

Comment: Sorry didn;t see it but i changed some things

Comment: Do you still getting the same error? Is the code you posted all that you have?

Comment: I changed my code to `root.addNode(root.b)` and I am now getting `Multiple markers at this line
 - Syntax error on token ")", delete this 
  token
 - Syntax error on token "(", delete this 
  token`

Comment: That line doesn't look like it'd throw that error. Please post more of your code.

Comment: @PakkuDon not sure what else to post =/ that is pretty much all of it. I'm a bit new to Java so the line `root.addNOde(root,b)` is not in the `main` not sure if that makes a difference

Comment: @Liondancer, where do you call the root.addNode(root,b) ?

Comment: @sasankad I'm using eclipse so I have been creating new files for each class. I have a test class where it contains all my methods that I use to interact with all the other classes that I've created. These methods are defined outside of my main (inside test class) but is still inside the test class.

Comment: Eclipse tells you exactly where the error is (file and line number). Post **that** and a few lines before and a few lines after. Ideally, **all your code**

Comment: @Liondancer, it should be root.addNode(root,b) not root.addNode(root.b), that's how you typed it in your comments. is that the case or it's just a typo?

Answer (score 2):

change it to

```
a.addNode(root, b);
```

It's because the `addNode(…)` method above takes two arguments. 
Hope this helps :)

Comment: i used `root.addNode(...)` instead but I am getting a different error now =/

Comment: mind posting your code exactly as it is on pastebin so i can take a better look at it and test it out again? because its working fine on my machine.

Answer (score -1):

```
public class LinkedListNode {
    public LinkedListNode next;
    int data;


    // constructor
    LinkedListNode(int newData) {
        this.data = newData;
    }

    public void addNode(LinkedListNode root, LinkedListNode node) {
        if (root.next == null) {
            root.next = node;
        }
        else {
            addNode(root.next, node);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
        LinkedListNode root = new LinkedListNode(4);    // root
        LinkedListNode a = new LinkedListNode(16);
        LinkedListNode b = new LinkedListNode(8);
        LinkedListNode c = new LinkedListNode(23);
        LinkedListNode d = new LinkedListNode(99);
        LinkedListNode e = new LinkedListNode(1);
        LinkedListNode f = new LinkedListNode(2);
        LinkedListNode g = new LinkedListNode(5);
        LinkedListNode h = new LinkedListNode(12);

        root.addNode(root, b);
    }
}
```

Comment: How is this meant to help OP?